# How to install python3 on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, for-loop, download

Hey guys so I’m new to downloading stuff like this but I really need help on how I can download python3 on my Mac, so I downloaded the Xcode from my App Store,and I’ve been trying to install the python3 on my MacBook Air from my terminal but all I get is command not found [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aVtV.jpg)

Comment: [check the site here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/)

Comment: It’s done downloading the home brew pls what next

Answer (score 0):

install home brew

install python by brew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install python
```

here is detail link

https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/

Comment: Pls after I typed Xcode-select- -install I got an error saying command line tools are already installed, use “software update” to install updates.pls what do I do

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://www.python.org/downloads/) to download the latest version of python.
Download the .PKG file and install.

Please check if python3 is installed or not using the `python3 --version` command in the terminal.